# Does UIKit have classes for contextual popups?

Tags: ios, uikit

A number of apps use contextual popups that look a bit like a "speech bubble."  They have a little tail to indicate their context, ie. the control that displayed them.  Are there standard UIKit (or open source) classes to create these?

[image: uikit contextual popup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That thing you see there is an example of `UIActionSheet` on the iPad, and it looks different on the iPhone. You can make other popup-type things using `UIPopoverController`, which is iPad only.

Answer (score 0):

Your options for menus (two of which have been mentioned by Colin already):

- UIActionSheet, which is what you've pictured. On iPad it shows up like your image, I believe because the system places it inside a UIPopoverController. On iPhone it is full-screen, like so:

[image: UIActionSheet on iPhone/iPod Touch]

- UIPopoverController, which put any arbitrary view in a popover (iPad only).
- UIMenuController, which shows popover menus (available on iPhone/iPad in iOS 4 and greater).

For most things you'll want to go with UIActionSheet or UIMenuController, as UIPopoverController is iPad only.